# Cannot run as a non-admin impersonated user - access is denied

Tags: c#, impersonation, non-admin

I do impersonation of a non-admin user account in an app that is running as an admin user (using `LogonUser()`, `DuplicateToken()` and `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate()` functions). Since this user account is temporary, I also need to load a user profile (using `LoadUserProfile()` native function). All methods execute successfully (no last error is set) and the current identity is the impesonated non-admin user as expected. However, when I try to run a new process with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()`, I get an error:

Access is denied.

When I try to manually execute the same scenario with runas /profile /user:mynonadmin user, everything works fine.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this a while back.

The impersonated user did not have access to the CWD which was set on the Process object.  Create a ProcessStartInfo object and set the working directory to a location the impersonated user has access to.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation with a service project. Here is some over-simplified pseudo code to give you an idea of what I was doing:

```
uint ConsoleSessionID = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()
WTSQueryUserToken(ConsoleSessionID, out hToken)
IsUserInAdminGroup(hToken)
DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, ref sa, SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, out IntPtr DuplicateToken)
WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(new SafeAccessTokenHandle(DuplicateToken), () =>
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = ...
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = ...
    p.WorkingDirectory = ...
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; // Elevated!
    p.Start();
}
```

This worked ABSOLUTELY FINE when logging into Windows using the local Administrator account.

However, if I created a "Test_User" account that was a member of the administrators group, I was getting ACCESS DENIED OR a 0xc0000142 exception from Process.Start().

[Allow service to interact with desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKETC.png)

After checking "Allow service to interact with desktop", now whether I used the actual local Administrator account, or any other account that is a member of the local administrators group, my service can now start an elevated application in the context of the logged-on user.

Of course I went back and updated my code for installing the service, to ensure the SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS flag was set, so this option was set programmatically.

Hope this helps someone...